# iOS 9 Application Transport Security debugging

Tags: security, http, nsurlconnection, ios9, nsurlsession

Ok so in the new version of iOS we are required to use secure connections for all network communications. I had assumed that this would cause me no issues as our app does this anyway, however:

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
```

this fella started cropping up!

I assume that this is due to a connection being made in one of the 3rd party libraries that our app includes but can't seem to work out which. Furthermore, I have included the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key in my plist (just for debugging) which makes the logged error go away, however, when then connected to Charles (a proxy application) I can see no insecure connections being made from my app :(

Is there any way to find the offending code that is causing this log?